Is $\mathrm{ZF}^-$ consistent with an Axiom of Countability?
$\mathrm{ZF}^-$ is $\mathrm{ZF}$ minus the power set axiom. $\mathrm{ZF}^-$ is relatively consistent with $\mathrm{ZF}^- + \mathrm{V}=\mathrm{L}$, and $\mathrm{L}$ well orders the universe $\mathrm{V}$ of $\mathrm{ZF}^- + \mathrm{V}=\mathrm{L}$. Moreover, $\mathrm{ZF}^- + \mathrm{V}=\mathrm{L}$ has natural models which we think are countable, e.g. one built up from the ordinal $\beta_0$ for ramified analysis.
Does $\mathrm{ZF}^- + \mathrm{V}=\mathrm{L}$ permit the addition of an Axiom of Countability which states that there is a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathrm{V}?$

Short version: no, not in any way I can see.
First of all, there's a language issue: since a surjection $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow V$ would be a proper class, it's not clear how to even state your proposed axiom.
We can avoid this issue by looking at an expanded language $\{\in, F\}$ and the theory $\mathsf{ZF^-+V=L}$ + "$F$ is a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $V$." However, this isn't very interesting: if we don't exend the Separation/Replacement schemes of $\mathsf{ZF}^-$ to include formulas involving the function $F$ then this is in fact a conservative extension of $\mathsf{ZF^-+V=L}$ (just take an externally-countable model of $\mathsf{ZF^-+V=L}$ and interpret $F$ as an appropriate bijection). On the other hand, if we do extend the schemes, then we get an inconsistent theory since we can diagonalize against $F$ via $\{n\in\omega: n\not\in F(n)\}$.
(Incidentally, this "folding-in-the-new-symbol" issue crops up in  more interesting ways when more intricate objects are involved; see e.g. the various ways of making sense of $\mathsf{ZF}$ + "$j$ is an elementary embedding $V\rightarrow V$," as mentioned in this old post. But in the present case, I don't see any options between triviality and inconsistency.)

Incidentally, at least the slightly weaker statement $\forall x\exists f(f$ is a surjection from $\omega$ to $x)$ appears to be true in $\mathrm{ZF}^- + \mathrm{V}=\mathrm{L}$. But I am not sure whether that has any interest here.

@FrodeAlfsonBjørdal As in a previous question of yours, that statement is not provable in $\mathsf{ZF^-+V=L}$ alone!

A consequence of the previous comment here seems to be: $\forall x\forall \alpha(x\in\mathrm{L}\alpha\to\exists f\exists \beta(f\in\mathrm{L}\beta\ & \ f$ surjects from $\omega$ to $x)).$

@FrodeAlfsonBjørdal Again, if you further add an axiom saying that every set is countable. And yes, even in ZF as long as $\alpha<\omega_1^L$ we have that for every (nonempty) $x\in L_\alpha$ there is some surjective $f:\omega\rightarrow x$ in $L$, and so in $L_\beta$ for some (countable) large enough $\beta$.

I see. One would need to take it as an additional axiom

We crossed again.

So doesn't $\forall x,\alpha(x\in\mathrm{L}\alpha\to\exists f\exists \beta(f\in\mathrm{L}\beta \ & \ f$ surjects from $\omega$ to $ x))$ amount to a clear and perhaps useful statement of the proposed axiom, then?

Noah, your $j:V\to V$ example is the main idea underlying the Wholeness Axiom, due to Paul Corazza. See, for example, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s001530050169.

I suggested the following answer: Use e.g. $\mathrm{ZF^-+V=L_{\beta_0}},$ where $\mathrm{L}{\beta_0}$ is the least $\mathrm{L}$-model of $\mathrm{ZF}^-$. Extend the approximating functions $\forall x,\alpha(x\in\mathrm{L}\alpha\to \exists f,\beta(f\in\mathrm{L}\beta \ & \ f $ surjects from $\omega$ to  $x))$ in the comments, to the other answer,  with "there is a surjection $\mathrm{E}\in \mathrm{L}{\beta_0+1}\setminus\mathrm{L}{\beta_0},$ from $\omega\in\mathrm{L}{\beta_0}$ to $\mathrm{V}$".

@NoahSchweber That there can be no surjection $in$ the $\mathrm{V}$ of $\mathrm{ZF}^-$ from  $\omega$ to $\mathrm{V}$ also follows immediately from replacement.

Use e.g. $\mathrm{ZF^-+V=L_{\beta_0}},$ where $\mathrm{L}_{\beta_0}$ is the least $\mathrm{L}$-model of $\mathrm{ZF}^-$. Extend the approximating functions $\forall x,\alpha(x\in\mathrm{L}_\alpha\to \exists f,\beta(f\in\mathrm{L}_\beta \ \& \ f $ surjects from $\omega$ to  $x))$ in the comments, to the other answer,  with "there is a surjection $\mathrm{E}\in \mathrm{L}_{\beta_0+1}\setminus\mathrm{L}_{\beta_0},$ from $\omega\in\mathrm{L}_{\beta_0}$ to $\mathrm{V}$".
